# Scikit-Learn DBSCAN creating a cluster with two highly disconnected islands

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

In this case: *a picture is worth a thousand words* ..

**Hello Purple Cluster!**

[image]

How did this come about?  First - to describe the data and the settings for `DBSCAN`:

- 100 data points
- Using a *custom* distance metric to generate a *precomputed distance matrix*
- The custom distance metric is simple: **Only consider the `r0` (x-distance)**

Everything besides that  ***rogue pair of purple points*** looks precisely as desired.  How did that purple cluster jump clear over the *Yellow Wall* and claim that rogue pair of points on the top left?

**Update**   It has been verified that there are exactly three clusters. I.e. this is not a bug in choosing three colors to denote four clusters.
The verification was directly from the dbscan predicted outputs (not some hypothesis of mine):

Here that is:

```
NumClusters is 3 counts are (array([-1,  0,  1]), array([ 8, 67, 25]))
```

**Another update**  To clarify: the 2 purple points are being added to the far right cluster (also in purple). They are *not* a *fourth* cluster. So the question is - why are those points being added to the *furthest away* cluster instead of the nearby green and yellow ones?

Comment: >>> "it has been verified that there are exactly three clusters". Different algos may have different opinions on what a cluster is.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov The verification was via the output generated by DBSCAN : i'm not guessing.  Will add that to the question to be clear.

Comment: This only means that DBSCAN thinks those two points are different enough to form a separate cluster.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov What are you talking about?  Those 2 points were added to that cluster to the far right. How does that happen when there are 2 other clusters right next door?  You seem to misunderstand that the two points are in some _fourth_ cluster.

Comment: It is not me talking about, It's DBSCAN.

Comment: You have not provided any assistance in explaining why `DBSCAN` would put two points in the *farthest away* cluster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208364/discussion-between-javadba-and-sergey-bushmanov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting.  I added the *cluster number* and we see that for the *purple* it is **-1**.

[image]

That means **NO CLUSTER**   . So that's how the pair in the upper left can "share" the same "cluster" with the ones on the far right: they do not actually share the *cluster* but just the identifier that `sckit-learn` uses for *NO* cluster.

Comment: did you play with `epsilon`?

Comment: Oh yes - that is _after all_ the core tuning parameter.  The above makes sense now: I just needed an understanding that the purple points are unclustered